# Specifically Prompt user when to allow Push Notifications

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

Hey I'm looking to prompt Push Notification after a user presses a button instead of it asking as soon as the app launches. How would I do that? This is what I have in my app delegate.

```
 OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: "myKey")

 if application.responds(to: #selector(UIApplication.registerUserNotificationSettings(_:))) {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)


        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    } else {

        let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [UIRemoteNotificationType.badge, UIRemoteNotificationType.alert, UIRemoteNotificationType.sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: types)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use a UIButton that is linked to an IBAction? In that way you'll need to change the application to UIApplication.shared

Comment: tried it, but it seems to still show when the app launches. it has something to do w/ OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: "myKey") but I don't know what I'm supposed to replace launchOptions with